# Responding to the "Before you switch" textbox for Edge in Default Apps crashes the settings

Tags: windows-10, crash, microsoft-edge, default-settings

I want to switch my default web browser from Edge to something else, but when I try to it gives me [this textbox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdkpN.png) Normally, when I respond to this textbox on other computers it goes fine, but for some reason on my current laptop it causes the whole Settings window to crash. Both options cause the window to crash, but I can click off the textbox to close it and not crash, and Windows Edge and the browser I want to switch to also run fine.

I've also tried to follow what Microsoft support has said where you attempt to repair or restart the problematic applications, but every time I try it tells me there's nothing wrong and continues to fail to switch my default browser. I can also switch other default applications just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but shouldn't opening the other browser and waiting for the Default Browser Notification pop-up solve the problem? I know for a fact that Chrome keeps pegging me to switch default browsers. You could also try to hunt through settings of the other browser and make it default through there.

Sorry if this is incorrect. All in all, pretty shady practices by Microsoft!

Comment: When Chrome asks me to switch it to the default browser, it just takes me to Windows 10's Default Apps Settings, so the problem remains. Same thing for its settings. I've even tried switching it to Internet Explorer, and it still crashes all the same.